# How to limit results of File::Find::Rule

Tags: perl

I have to search a large directory structure of files with [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) (or similar).

For testing purposes I'd like top stop after a certain ammount of found files.
I've used `->exec()` with `state` or global scope variables, but i haven`t found a way to quit the searching without the use of Labels... Is there a way to do that elegantly?

Comment: You could throw an exception from `exec()` and put an `eval` around the `in()` to catch it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to abort the search, is by calling `die` from the `exec` handler, then use `eval` to catch the exception in the outer scope. For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $count = 0;
my @files;
eval {
    File::Find::Rule->new->file
      ->exec( sub { die if $count++ > 10; push @files, $_[2]; return 1; })->in('.');
};
if( $@ ) {
    say "Aborted search after ", $count - 1, " matches";
}
```